# how to remove ACM Reference format box in sig-conf template?

Tags: acm

I found the following part titled ACM Reference format in the body. How can I get rid of this?

ACM Reference format:
Ben Trovato, G.K.M. Tobin, Lars Thørv¨ald, Lawrence P. Leipuner, Sean Fog-
arty, Charles Palmer, John Smith, and Julius P. Kumquat. 1997. SIG Proceed-
ings Paper in LaTeX Format. In Proceedings of ACM Woodstock conference,
El Paso, Texas USA, July 1997 (WOODSTOCK’97), 4 pages.
DOI: 10.475/123 4

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SX. Without showing any code you have used it will most likely only be guessing on you could get rid of this. Could you please edit your question and provide a [minimal working example (most probably) with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows this behavior.

Answer (score 50):

`\settopmatter{printacmref=false}`

Related options can be found in Section 2 of the [class documentation](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf).

Comment: What other options are available to modify here?

Comment: This link is no longer valid, it would be nice to list a few more options.

Comment: Here is the permanent address http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/acmart.pdf